# Need to extract specific text out of NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, substring, nsscanner

I am pulling user information from my server's database. When the user is found in the database, an object is returned to me and when I NSLog the object it looks like this:

```
(
    "<PFUser:981038hajsh98:(null)> {\n    \"Phone_Number\" = 5859921091;\n    email = \"usersemail@aol.com\";\n    username = jeff849;\n    verificationCode = 3240;\n}"
)
```

I need a way to extract just the "username" value. So with the above example, I would need to extract this exactly: `jeff849`

How can I do this?

Edit: The object that I need to extract a specific substring out of is an NSString object.

Comment: You need to show us what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't a string, it's a [PFUser](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFUser.html) object from the Parse API class. When you log an object, the `description` method is called, which is what you are seeing above. Given that it's a user object, use the `username` property to get the value.

```
NSLog(@"%@", pfuser.username);
```

That's assuming the variable that your PFUser object is `pfuser`. You're obviously logging that object somehow to get that string.

*Update*

Looking at the log it might be an `NSArray` of `PFUser`'s. In that case

```
for (PFUser *user in databaseUsers) {
    NSLog(@"%@", user.username);
}
```

Comment: Jason, yes I am using Parse. It is scanning the parse database for a phone number, and then if it finds that phone number, it returns the entire row for that user. That is why the object prints to the console with a username, email, verification code, etc. Any idea how I can just grab the username text?

Comment: Use the username property as shown above (according the the API docs) I haven't used Parse.